# Adobe Acrobat Date Picker/Field Returns an Error Every Time on One Specific Form But Works on All Other Forms

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript, livecycle-designer, adobe-form

The date picker/field on one specific form returns an error every time but works on all other forms. Even when I manually try to enter it using the correct formatting, it still returns an error. Below is the code attached to the field. The first piece of code is attached to the exit event and contains the error message returned while the second piece of code is attached to the change event. Is this caused by a bug with my version of Adobe or is my code causing this issue? I know there were issues with the date picker in previous versions of Adobe. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Current Version:

2021.007.20102

Exit Event:

```
if((!this.isNull) && (!this.execValidate()))
{
    xfa.host.messageBox("You have entered an invalid date. Please select a date from the date picker.");
    this.rawValue = null;
})
```

Change Event:

```
if (xfa.event.newText.match(/[^0-9\/]/)) 
{  
    xfa.event.change = "";  
}
```

[image: JavaScript Error Message from Exit Event]

Comment: What is the error that is returned?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah It's returning the error in the exit event.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any message in the error?

Comment: There are no other messages besides the one in the Exit event. I have added a screenshot to my post.

Comment: Hmm, what does the `this.execValidate` function and `this.isNull` look like?

Comment: Well, the current code is supposed to check to make sure it's not null, and if there is data in the field, it validates it against any requirements/validation formatting configured for the field.

Comment: I'm wondering if my piece of code is always evaluating to ```True``` once data has been entered in.

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering that as well